# JQuery, why won't my mousemove listener not pass the event object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mouseevent, mousemove

I'm using the following the code.

```
var cursorXPos;
var cursorYPos;

$(document).mousemove( cursorLocation(evt) );

function cursorLocation (evt) {
 cursorXPos = evt.pageX;
 cursorYPos = evt.pageY;
}
```

But this is giving me an error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property `pageX` of undefined.

However, if I use an anonymous function, the event object is passed and everything works fine.

```
$(document).mousemove( function (evt) {
 cursorXPos = evt.pageX;
 cursorYPos = evt.pageY;
});
```

Comment: The first snippet executes `cursorLocation` and then uses its return value as a reference to an actual event handler. You're not returning anything, hence the reference will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass the parameter in the function when you bind the event. You just pass the name of the event, and javascript handles the parameters for you.

```
var cursorXPos;
var cursorYPos;

$(document).mousemove( cursorLocation ); // <-- here 

function cursorLocation (evt) {
    cursorXPos = evt.pageX;
    cursorYPos = evt.pageY;
}
```

Comment: @arun-p-johny Thanks for your help guys. It's working now. I'm curious what happens if the function has more than 1 parameter, how does javascript know which parameter to pass the event object to?

Comment: If you mean the functions used in jQuery events for example, jQuery handles the propagation of the event to the function you specified, so they (almost) always give the `(event, ui)` parameters with every call. You can also define your methods with custom names like `(foo, bar)`, in that case `foo` would just be the `event` parameter with another name.

Comment: Say my method has parameters (foo, bar, name). I'm presuming event and ui are always the first objects to be passed by the event handler, so they'll occupy foo and bar. But how would I pass a name object?

Comment: Sorry about the late answer. You would do that like in [this pastie](http://pastie.org/10350699). When you bind an event with jQuery, the function is always locked to the 2 parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a function reference to `mousemove`, don't invoke it(by adding `()`)

```
$(document).mousemove( cursorLocation );
```

Comment: Damn, beat me by 20 seconds :)